# Is this lactobacillus?

Tags: contamination, bacteria, lactobacillus

My last batch had a thin whitish 'membrane' on top of it and some white spots, visible on the picture bellow.

I think I saw something similar on a blog a while ago, attributed to a lactobacilus infection.

Taste was not too bad, but the smell was a bit strange, I went ahead and bottled 3 days ago.

What is that? Should I be prepared for bottle bombs?

[image: lactobacilus?]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit tricky to tell, but it could be early stages of a lactobacillus or pediococcus contamination. The flaky white patches are typical of lactobacillus, while short segments of ropes you see are typical of pediococcus, although I would swing towards lactobacillus on this one.

Lactobacillus contamination:

[image: Lactobacillus contamination]

Pediococcus contamination:

[image: Pediococcus contamination]

Either way, it's clearly a contamination of some kind, so best to be safe with the bottling and **bottle with plastic soda bottles**. Stored cold, any decrease in SG will take several months, and not all strains produce CO2 -  but I never take chances with glass.

Comment: Too late, got them on glass already. will follow closely and store cold as soon as it is carbonated. Is pediococcus contaminated beer safe To drink? That looks nasty.

Comment: hehe, yes, it's safe to drink - it it weren't, lambics wouldn't be half as popular as they are! On first sight it looks nasty, but then so does a krausen to some. It's a collection of dextrins, proteins and some slime to help keep oxygen out of the beer. No pathogens harmful to humans can grow in beer.

Comment: That being said, not everyone likes sour beer. Me for instance. Can't stand the stuff.

Comment: He asked if it was safe to drink - not to be blunt, but I don't see what your personal preference has to do with that. Sure, some people like it, others don't, but that's how it is with all types of beer.

Comment: I had a pediococcus-style spiderweb appear on a black English Pale Ale once, right at the end of dry hopping. I kegged it anyway and it was delicious, with no noticeable sour flavor. Don't worry about an infection until the beer tastes like: bandaids; burnt rubber; wet goat; pineapple; or cherry pie. And even then, if its any of those last 3, just let it ride a year and call it a Flemish Sour.