# Is my beer infected? from an amateur. Posted a picture

Tags: fermentation, beer, contamination, primary-fermentation, primary

I used only DME and hops to boil the wort. Added dry yeast directly. I looked up on the internet for similar pictures but couldn't find any. I know every beer ferments differently. So I thought I better ask before I dump it. Any help is highly appreciated. This is what it looks like -

[image]

Comment: That definitely looks suspicious to me. I've never seen anything like that. I don't want to say anything for certain just from a picture, but if I saw something like that in my fermenter, my first thought would that it's gone bad.

Comment: How did you sanitize your equipment?

Comment: Taste it or smell it. Looks might not be a good guide

Answer (score 5):

This looks like Pediococcus contamination:  see here [Is this lactobacillus?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/9569/is-this-lactobacillus)

More information about spoilage here: https://www.craftbrewingbusiness.com/news/four-bacteria-that-will-ruin-your-beer/

Lack of sanitation might have cause this.

Answer (score 1):

*Obligatory Disclaimer*

*I'm not at all experienced with brewing ... but I have some pretty good experience with spawning and cultivating mushrooms.*

That sure looks like a fungal growth to me. Classic mycelium threads, building into a network.

Some Google Images for you that look pretty similar.

[Google Images : mycelium fungus](https://www.google.com/search?q=mycelium&tbm=isch&chips=q:mycelium,g_1:fungus:5-0-mnlUgJo%3D&client=ubuntu&hs=AG9&hl=en-GB&ved=2ahUKEwi23_2c2KTpAhVN1-AKHTpKCUUQ4lYoAXoECAEQFw&biw=1351&bih=645)

As with all unknown fungi/mushrooms - until you know exactly what it is, I would recommend caution.